# IIS not recognizing filechanges

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a IIS running on my webserver. I developed a rest api based on a mvc 4 web api. the problem i have at the moment is that when I put new / changed files onto the IIS that the IIS is not "recognizing" them.

lets say for example i changed one service - put the new file on the server - server thinks he still has the old file. I observer this behaviour because when i call the service i still get the old result - not the new result as implemented in visual studio locally. I have no clue why the IIS is acting like that...

Comment: Did you just add/change the C# file without recompiling?

Comment: no, i did/do a rebuild everytime

Comment: Can you please describe exactly what file are you updating on the server.

Comment: When i implement a new service for example in the CategoriesController.cs - then I delete the old CategoriesController.cs file and paste the new modified CategoriesController.cs into the direcotry. 

as that was not working anymore - in the past it did - i deleted the whole project and paste the new one. didnt work either.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding between ASP.NET web site and ASP.NET web application. The latter is compiled to a DLL (in the bin folder), the former you can use as you are doing now. IIRC, all MVC projects are web applications.

Comment: thank you for that hint. it is working now! thank you!

Comment: If you write your entire solution as an answer, you can accept it, and score some points ;p

Answer (score 1):

As leppie already mentioned in the comments, I had a wrong understanding of ASP.NET web sites and ASP.NET web applications.

As a solution, I had to do a rebuild to compile the DLL again and then deploy it to the IIS.